# How to apply OOP principles in a new C# console application

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to work out how best to structure objects within a new C# Console Application so that it conforms to OOP principles so that it is reusable, maintainable, extendable and unit testable.

I have the following task:

1. The console application will be triggered from a task scheduler
2. It reads in an xml file from a file share
3. The xml file contains numeric data that needs to be aggregated
4. The result of this aggregation needs to be emailed to the end user

For steps 1 and 2, I have planned to create the following classes:

- FileToStringTransformer (this will read in the contents of the xml file from the file share and bring it into the application as a string - Isolating this class allows us to unit test the other classes without having a dependency on the file share and also gives us the flexibility to change the source location of the xml from a file on disk to say a database without affecting the other classes)
- StringToXDocumentTransformer (this will change the string object to an XDocument object)
- XDocumentToDomainObjectTransformer (this will map the XDocument Object to the Domain Object so that it is easy to aggregate the numeric data)

I was planning to make the XDocumentToDomainObjectTransformer object "have a" StringToXDocumentTransformer and the StringToXDocumentTransformer object "have a" FileToStringTransformer object. This is so that a single call to the XDocumentToDomainObjectTransformer object will call methods on the other two objects to stop you having to explicitly write the calls to all three classes everywhere you want to transform a file on disk to a domain object.

But I realised a drawback of this is that you won't be able to reuse the classes in isolation from one another - I couldn't say reuse the XDocumentToDomainObjectTransformer class alone because the dependency tree includes the other two classes. What is the best way to design objects for steps 1 and 2 of the task so that they conform to OOP principles?

Comment: Make a pipeline class that has the transformers.  This way you can get re-use when you implement new kinds of transformers and mix and match them at runtime by combining them in different ways. Another way is something like this https://martinfowler.com/articles/collection-pipeline/

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition that you won't be able to reuse the classes in isolation is correct. The second issue is that it is generally good practice to make your transformers stateless.

The design model you appear to be leaning towards is typically referred to as "functional programming".

Under that model you would have a:

FileToStringTransformBlock

StirngToXDocumentTransformBlock

XDocumentToDomainObjectTransformBlock

Which you could link together in a single pipeline as suggested above.

For best practice I would suggest using a [Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline), which has a really clean example that uses 4 chained transformations.